# Errror Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::appends()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Hola estoy queriendo mostrar solo los registros que el usuario loggeado inserto en la base de datos en la vista Index, para que no pueda ver los registros de otros usuarios del sistema pero obtengo el siguiente error:

> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::appends() 
>   (View:C:\laragon\www\sistema\resources\views\admin\perfil\index.blade.php)
>   Previous exceptions

Tengo cada registro con su respectivo id de usuario insertado en la base de datos, a continuación el código:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Perfil;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\perfil;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class perfilController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $keyword = $request->get('search');
        $perPage = 25;

        if (!empty($keyword)) {
            $perfil = perfil::where('Logo', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                ->orWhere('NombreEmpresa', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                ->orWhere('RFC', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                ->orWhere('Direccion', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                ->orWhere('Telefono', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                ->orWhere('category', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                ->orWhere('Serial', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
                ->latest()->paginate($perPage);
        } else {
            $perfil = perfil::latest()->paginate($perPage);
        }
          $perfils = perfil::all();
          $perfilID = Auth::user()->id;
          $perfil = $perfils->where('perfilID', $perfilID);
          return view('admin.perfil.index', compact('perfil'));
    }
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: en esta línea no te hace falta el `get()` al final? `$perfil = $perfils->where('perfilID', $perfilID);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues me da que estás haciendo mal varias cosas. No entiendo por qué haces toda la parte del filtrado según parámetros recibidos y obtienes los registros paginados para luego hacer una llamada al método `all()`

Deberías renombrar la clase `perfil`, ponerla con la primera letra en mayúscula y luego importarla para que funcione:

```
use App\Perfil;
```

Luego, pones como condición imprescindible el perfil del usuario en los filtros de paginación:

```
$perfilID = Auth::user()->id;
if (!empty($keyword)) {
    $perfil = Perfil::where(function ($query) use ($keyword) {
        $query->where('Logo', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
            ->orWhere('NombreEmpresa', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
            ->orWhere('RFC', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
            ->orWhere('Direccion', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
            ->orWhere('Telefono', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
            ->orWhere('category', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%")
            ->orWhere('Serial', 'LIKE', "%$keyword%");
        })
        ->where('perfilID', $perfilID)->latest()->paginate($perPage);
} else {
    $perfil = Perfil::where('perfilID', $perfilID)->latest()->paginate($perPage);
}
```

Y después ya devuelves la vista:

```
return view('admin.perfil.index', compact('perfil'));
```

Comment: Perfecto! funciono! muchas gracias, solo una observacion, te falto incluir el '$' o da el error: Use of undefined constant perfilID - assumed 'perfilID' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Comment: Me alegro. Acepta, por favor, la respuesta como válida de modo que sirva para otros y a mi!